# How to get alert message on second click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know that how can I get an alert message on second click of a button, not on a first click.

ex: `<input type="button" value="Message" onclick="showMessage()">`

```
function showMessage(){
    alert("It's a second click message"); // this alert message should be shown on second click of a button
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to `alert` after every first click..?

Comment: The question is somewhat ambiguous. You want to track second click/each click after second click/each even click

Answer (score 7):

Use counter instead..

```js
var count = 0; //global variable
function showMessage() {
  if (count++ == 1) { //Compare and then increment counter
    alert("It's a second click message"); //this alert message will be shown only on second click of a button
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Message" onclick="showMessage()">
```

Comment: This is correct answer. OP has said `second click` not `after second click`

Comment: @Manwal As per OPs question he wants on 2nd click not on consecutive 2nd clicks.. :)

Comment: @Tushar Thank you.. looks bit clean now.. :) and yea more efficient too.. :)

Comment: Hi all, Thank for your help, the above code snippet has resolved my issue.

Comment: Anytime.. @Dhana Do not forget to mark any solution as answer whichever you feel deemed to solve your issue.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not looking for the [dbclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dblclick) event, then you can use a flag to check whether it is the second click to show the alert

```js
var flag;

function showMessage() {
  if (flag) {
    alert("It's a second click message"); // this alert message should be shown on second click of a button
  } else {
    flag = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Message" onclick="showMessage()">
```

Comment: Don't forgot to add `flag=false;` after alert so it won't work 3'rd time.

Comment: It will keep on giving alerts after first click, I am not sure what he is asking, I guess It should only `alert` for send click..

Answer (score 2):

Consider this code, This is alert message after every alternate click:

```js
var count = 1;

function showMessage() {
  if (!(count++ % 2))
    alert("It's a second click message"); //this alert message at every second click
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Message" onclick="showMessage()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use `ondblclick` instead of `onclick`

**Like below**

```
<input type="button" value="Message" ondblclick="showMessage()">
```

Comment: What if user wait for few seconds after first click, OP might want to track the _second_ click

Comment: @Tushar sh/e did not mention that and you also started the comment with what if that's why my answer is there based on the question.

Comment: Yes, thats why I didn't downvote your answer as the question is not clear, I've added comment on question for clarification. Lets see what OP really want :)

Comment: @Tushar As from question, I did not feel that he want to capture every click post second click. It seems fairly straight forward that he want alert message on second click not on first. You cannot downvote even if he says what you have asked.

Comment: Hi Akki619, ondblclick event is worked too. Thanks for your help.